# How to fix Wunknown-pragmas gcc warning

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma, gcc-warning

I have a code snippet, here I have put a `#pragma`. This gives `Wunknown-pragmas` warning :

```
warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout<<"Helloworld\n";

  #ifdef __GNUC__
  #pragma warning( push )
  #pragma warning( disable : warning )
  cout<<  "I am in warning free section"<<endl;
  #pragma warning( pop )

  #endif

  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this at code level?

Comment: AFAIK, pragmas are compiler specific. Are you sure it's applicable for your case?

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled about the `#ifdef __GNUC__`. As the compiler says - it cannot read the `#pragma` and thus ignores it. That it yields a warning is enabled with command line option `-Wunknown-pragmas`. Btw. it looks like a [MS VC pragma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/2c8f766e.aspx) in opposition to the [GCC pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use pragmas in GCC. It should be more like:

```
#include<iostream>

 //example function that
 //complains if its result is unused
__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__)) int foo() { return 42; }

using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout<<"Helloworld\n";
  foo();

  #ifdef __GNUC__
  #pragma GCC diagnostic push
  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-result" 
  foo(); //no complaints here
  cout<<  "I am in warning free section"<< endl;
  #pragma GCC diagnostic pop

  #endif

   return 0;
}
```

See the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for more information.